# What should I do when a question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, editing, close-reasons

A question has been marked as duplicate saying it has already an answer on another question.

However it does not and even if the question could sound similar, it is a totally different problem.

I do not think it happens very often as it's very unlikely that 5 different people can miss such subtitle situation but I was wondering what should I do?

FYI the question I'm referring to is this one: [Error after installing patch 7405 on Magento 1.4.0.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/98601/2380)

Comment: This might seem like I'm targeting your meta questions, I'm not! This question has also been asked a thousand times across the network. No need to ask it again.

Comment: No worries mate that's my bad as I said on my other comment I'll do better the next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (and only) thing to do is to post here in Meta for us to review. I have reopened and added a comment to the answer to signify that it is due to the version you are running.

Comment: Great thanks for that

Comment: I think there really needs to be a mechanism where the author of the question can appeal the closure or post more information to clarify why their question is not a duplicate. My questions have been incorrectly closed several times and it's fucking maddening.