# Why the question was marked as "unclear" if it is totally clear?

Tags: discussion

Today 5 users marked this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/close/120294 as *"Unclear what you asking"* when the question is totally clear. How could this happen? What can look unclear in this question? I have nominated this question to reopen, but this is not the main goal because I only want to understand why 5 of 5 reviewers did make such a decision?

Note: here the description of the *"Unclear what you asking"*:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

**PS:** I read similar question [What should I do when a question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/815/what-should-i-do-when-a-question-has-been-incorrectly-marked-as-duplicate) where the answer from the moderator was

> The best (and only) thing to do is to post here in Meta for us to review.

because of that, I ask this question here.

**UPDATE:**

In both cases (see [answer](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2322/37497) given by Mr. sv3n), there are [candidates for moderators](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) among the reviewers:

- [Sander Mangel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel)
- [Keyur Shah](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2589/keyur-shah)
- [Manoj Deswal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54588/manoj-deswal)

**I would very much like to hear their opinion on this matter in context of election.**

Comment: please nominate atleast next time, we really & really need moderators like you......

Comment: Agree to @BabyinMagento ... missed your name at nomination list.

Answer (score 3):

Can we agree that it is not a good question? I wouldn't even call it "perfectly clear", but rather had down voted and commented than closing it immediately.

What's the problem with it you may ask.

It does not provide any context that would explain what OP is *actually* trying to achieve, what they already know or what they tried.

"using object manager" is oddly specific. If they know about the object manager, they should know how to get an object from it. That's all, the object manager does and it's the same for any class, so why the question about this particular collection?

Or are they looking for the right class name? That should have been mentioned in the question then.

Why do they even ask for the object manager? It should be used automatically via dependency injection. Do they have a reason not to? Do they not know about it? It might be a case of the [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

So many open questions from a badly worded one liner

Comment: Absolutely right. But the question should not be closed since it is answerable. We don't need to do strict scrutiny here since we already a stable site. Rather, we should encourage OP to improve his/her question by asking or instructing through a comment.

Comment: Yes, this question is very simple and could be googled in 1 minute, but... Why it marked as unclear? What exactly unclear in it? For the answer, we have the "Low Quality" mark, but if this mark does not exist for the question - I think we should not mark a question as unclear when it just has low quality. Does it have sense?

Comment: I agree @RajeevKTomy

Answer (score 3):

uchukhlebau, thanks for reaching out. In this case when I read the question it didn't come accross to me as clear. Maybe I misread it, that might very well be it.

Now, looking at the with the answers that provide context I do get it.
In general adding more context to your question might have helped here.

As @rajeev-k-tomy explains quite well if you do not agree with the closing there are several ways of responding to that. Also posting here is a good way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your point of view. I'm voted for you in the primary election and please, be not so strict in future :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Next time I will leave a comment motivating my decision, this might be more useful for someone else in the future

Comment: Commenting questions on the close-queue is hell of a job. So I recommend the "SKIP" button or preferably you can choose a right option from the closing reasons!!!

Comment: "Skip" should also be used more often for flags on comment  :P

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree. I guess it's just because a really short questions without some code, but its clear.

But therefor read tooltips of up/downvotes and use them. If there are possible duplicates, do I quick search.

First time I saw this review today I just **skipped** it, because I had no time to search for duplicate. I voted to reopen too ...

---

Same here ... [Allow edit product attributes on user permission](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211672/allow-edit-product-attributes-on-user-permission) ... first close vote was before I changed title and answered. Still no good description, but it was nearly clear what he was looking for.

---

Edit:

Sometime it's a split desicion ... asking for more information again and again takes time. Time that the author **should** have spent first. I agree with Fabian, there are too much questions with poor description/no effort ... so better flag as *"too broad"* or *"offtopic - with comment"*? Maybe it's more correct then use *"unclear"* flag. However ... if we are more strict at this side, "reopen" votes have to be checked more exact after edits.

---

Edit 2:

If you "skip" reviews, **they will** popup later again! So there is no need for a fast decision ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for another kind of question with the same problem. Based on it I updated my question, where I mentioned candidates for moderators election from the reviewers' list. It is very interesting to hear what are they thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

As @sv3n mentioned, this question is clear in my point of view. So you can do two things here.

1. You can reopen it. You can do this, if you have the privilege of [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).
2. If you do not have the privilege to reopen the question or you see that the reopen request is again getting rejected, then in that case you can flag that question to the moderator with an "other" reason and state that I would like to answer this question as it seems clear for me. In this case, if the moderator feels that its a genuine reason, then he will reopen it for you.

Other than this, one thing you can do to reopen a question is just edit that question. Editing a question will put the question in reopen request queue so that the moderators can evaluate it. But the tendency which I see here is such questions will remain as closed.

Now why do this happen?

Many reasons are there. But people have a tendency to close the question if the content is very less. Some people are too lazy to read the content and judge the question with it's heading. This trend is not good for the community.

I request all my fellow community members to read the content of a question in case you are dealing close queue. If you are not sure what should do with the question or answer (it may happen), then better skip that question rather than do a false judgement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as you say *Some people are too lazy to read the content and judge the question with it's heading.* and there are candidates for moderators among the reviewers, so it is very interesting, what they thinking about this problem and how they can moderate this community if they are so lazy to read two-lines question?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau the thing is we are not sure the people who you quoted in your comment doing their moderation like I described above. But.. yes it would be nice if we know their view point on this.